What is the largest number that is the digit sum of a $60$-digit square number?
I've found a solution $484$, which is sum of digits of $$998999898799899495979884898986874889889988568999999999889889=$$ $$=999499824312090360049170206833^2.$$
But with the first 50+ items, I got an empirical formula that a(n) appears to be approximately equal to $$(33*n-11)/4 $$I think the result should be in the range $[488,496]$.
Preliminary research:
I've also found that the largest number that is the digit sum of a 58-digit square number maybe 469, which comes from at least 3 solutions as square of $${94847245610929570838641435883, 94868329799780864312654168333, 98893781397011460159874958167}$$
Anyone can help me?

Why do you think the result is in that range?

With the first 50+ items, I got an empirical formula that a(n) appears to be approximately equal to (33*n-11)/4

Then include this info in the post. Your question might get closed soon. Please see how to ask a good question.

Thanks for your suggestion.

You might be interested in https://oeis.org/A068809 which doesn't go as far as you have gone but might serve as a check on your work.

@ Gerry Myerson:   Thanks. https://oeis.org/A067179/b067179.txt  is helpful too.

Related question on MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405922/the-largest-digital-sum-of-the-square-of-an-n-digit-number

However you found this amazing result , it will be very hard to beat it.

The formula is only empirical , there is no reason to believe it continues , also you are very close to the desired lower bound. I admit however that there is a possibility to still improve this result. If you tell us how you found your record , we can perhaps help.

I've found a larger solution 487, which is sum of digits of $899888998699999998999687939979978986989669884899789898989889=948624793424671142776753443167^2$
